# Barra de Progreso Multiple en html

Tags: html

Quiero hacer esto explicó: un usuario compra 1750 puntos, la barra se llena en color verde si completa la de 2000. y el obtiene el premio Numero 1. si realiza otra y completa la de 3000. Pues se llena la de 3000 gana el premio Numero 2 y si sigue comprando se va llenando cada barra SEPARADA. **IMPORTANTE** una barra es la continuación de la anterior es decir la suma de la de 2000 se suma a la de 3000 osea yo ho compre 2000 gallinas mañana compro mil gallinas total son 3000 entonces dos barras de progreso deben llenarse la de 2000 y la de 3000 en verde.

lo que tengo hecho es esto pero no sale dividido igual que la imagen

```html
<html>
  <progress max="2000" value="700"><!--Divide--><progress max="3000" value="50"><!--Divide--><progress max="5000" value="20"><!--continbua igual que la imagen-->


</html>
```

[image: Referencia a barra de progreso]

Comment: No entiendo muy bien qué quieres lograr, podrías editar tu pregunta para darte a entender mejor? Puedes usar comas o puntos para separar tus ideas.

Comment: hermano lea Bien ya edite y reedite y organize que parte usted no entiende? quizas me explique mal.por las sudas pondre puntos y comas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El tag `<progress>`, como cualquier otro, debe ser cerrado. Es decir, te falta el `</progress>` tras cada una. Sin él, el navegador considera que las barras de progreso están "anidadas" (una dentro de otra) y sólo muestra la más exterior, que es la primera de ellas.

Demo:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <progress max="2000" value="700"></progress>
    <progress max="3000" value="50"></progress>
    <progress max="5000" value="20"></progress>
  </body>
</html>
```